WebClient configuration overriding in Spring Boot
We can customize WebClientBuilder using WebClientCustomizer in one place. Then we can inject builders in service classes like this:
public Service(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
// some code
}

And they retain all customization. However, how to retain customization but remove or override one/few specific ones. For example, how to
override timeout,
change logging,
remove one header,
override error handling?
I am aware I could go WebClient.builder.build() but that seems no good as it gets rid of ALL customizations. Also it is against the strong Spring Boot recommendation to inject WebClient.Builder.
Seems like all options of local customization only adds customization, no way to change/override one or few.
